# Php Return substring at beginning of string as variable?

Tags: php

For example: In

```
"Why is the sky blue?"
```

how do i detect which one of these substrings:

```
"What is", 
"Who is", 
"Why is", 
"How is", 
"Where is", 
"When is"
```

is included at the beginning of the string and how do i then return that as a variable.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Can you show us what you have tried so far and why you are stuck? Then we can help you with your specific issue.

Comment: You could make an array with all substrings you are searching for, and then loop through that and check with strpos if its found. You could aswell use one of the array_* funcs to call strpos

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what u want here **"and how do i then return that as a variable"**, but u can check this solution and give more information:

```
<?php

$words = ['Who is', 'Why is', 'How is', 'Where is', 'When is'];

$query = 'Why is the sky blue?';

foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (substr($query, 0, strlen($word)) === $word) {
        $found = $word;
    }
}
```

So in this example at the end `$found` will contains **"Why is"**, it's good idea to check with `isset();` before use `$found;`

Comment: Instead of `echo $word;` put `$found = $word;` and then OP has a variable containing what was found

Comment: U are right, but for example i think `echo` is better, probably he can set variable if want.

Comment: He wants: _and how do i then return that as a variable_